# Pandas assign series to groupby results

Tags: pandas, group-by

Hi I'm a bit clueless about how to assign a series to groupby results.

I have dataframe A and B:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'TW':[0,1,0,0,1,0]})
B = pd.DataFrame({1:['A','B','C'], 2:['A','B','C']})
```

B's columns are representing A's ID information. I want to group A by ID and assign B's corresponding columns to replace the TW data. Here is what I want:

```
C = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'TW':['A','B','C','A','B','C']})
```

Could someone please help on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just melt `B`?

```
>>> pd.melt(B, var_name='Date', value_name='TW')
   Date TW
0     1  A
1     1  B
2     1  C
3     2  A
4     2  B
5     2  C
```

Comment: additional question: if I want to only let A['TW'] = B if A['Date'] == 1, want should I do?

Comment: `A.loc[A['Date'] == 1, 'TW'] = ...` I'm not sure what you mean because you would be assign the value in a given cell from `A` the entire dataframe `B`.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander's answer is the obvious one. But this is another way to go about it.

```
B.rename_axis('Date', 1).stack() \
    .reset_index('Date', name='TW') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```